# How do I push data to an observable from the textbox on pressing enter without doing blur?

Tags: knockout.js

Here is the set up:

I have a textbox bound to an observable.

The observable gets the value from the textbox on the change event of the textbox which, in its turn, happens on blur (or few other events like 'valueUpdate: afterkeydown' that we are not considering).

What I need is to make it also happen on hitting Enter, that is by hitting Enter the current value of the textbox is taken and pushed to the observable.

So I wrote a binding which listens to the keydown event of the textbox and, if the scan code is 13, it does.. What? Here is where I am not certain. Let me explain:

At this point I need the change event to happen somehow, but I have no direct control over it that is I cannot fire the change event on the element explicitly. So what I do instead is I blur and refocus on the textbox causing the change event to happen naturally. This blur/focus thing works, but introduces unwanted side effects which are hard to suppress..

So what I am ultimately looking for is **a way to start propagating the current value from the textbox to the observable** inside of my 'enter' binding. Which is to effectively simulate the change event that happens on loosing the focus **but without loosing the focus (doing blur)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.returnKey = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'keydown', function(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
           //evt.preventDefault();
           //evt.target.blur();
           valueAccessor(element.value);
        }
      });
    }
};
```

then your html should

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:message, returnKey:message" />
```

CHECK **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cDT5A/)**

Comment: I am sorry this is exactly what I have right now, and the problem with this is that you do 'blur' which is a problem. My question is how to do the same without blurring and refocusing.

Comment: yeah, seems like a right thing to do.. I've taken a look at the source code of the 'value' binder, it's a little bit more complex than this, which makes me think something could be missing in just straight setting the observable explicitly. I wish somebody who has expert knowledge of Knockout internals approved it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that perhaps you should be updating the value binding directly instead of the observable.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
```

That should do what you're wanting.